# SQL query and 3 tables with two different columns from the same table

Tags: sql

I need some assistance with a SQL query.

I have these tables:

[image: Tables]

I want to fetch this data:

[image: Result]

The problem is that I need to take products id only with which made both `action_id=1` and `action_id=2` and within some interval like from 2022-06-29 to 2022-08-29.

I don't understand how to make it with both different action_id-s? I tried queries like this:

```
SELECT 
    products.*, user_activities.created_at 
FROM 
    products 
JOIN 
    user_activities ON ((user_activities.action_id = $1 OR
                         user_activities.action_id = $2) AND
                        user_activities.product_id = products.id) 
WHERE 
    user_activities.created_at BETWEEN $2 AND $3;
```

Thank you for everyone who can help me with this.

**Update**: with my query I get two rows of the same product, because it have two different action_id and i want to receive data without duplicate it.

What inserted in tables:

```
INSERT INTO user_activities (id, action_id, product_id, created_at) VALUES ('00000000-1111-2000-0000-000000000000',  
        '00000000-0000-1000-0000-000000000000', 
        '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000005', '2004-10-19 10:23:54');

INSERT INTO user_activities (id, action_id, product_id, created_at) VALUES ('00000000-1111-3000-0000-000000000000', 
        '00000000-0000-2000-0000-000000000000', 
        '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000005', '2004-10-19 10:23:54');
```

I want to receive 1 row with the data of this product and when it was created:

```
ID, NAME, Description, Price, Category, Created_AT
```

As it has two action on the same product ID

Comment: Add sample data, expected result and result you get

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to use a nested where clause over a join for this kind of thing. `in` and `between` keywords could both potentially be useful for you here.

Comment: As for the error you get in the INSERT clauses, what is the primary key of user_activities? If it is id, you can't insert two rows with the same value for id

Comment: @mbd yes, you are right. My fault. I fixed that, but i still receive as a result 2 rows of the same product, because it has two different action_id's, but i want to receive only one, without duplicate. Can you halp me with this?)

Comment: If I understood correctly, you could group by user_activities.created_at, since it's the same in both actions, but it would still show more than one row per product if you have differents created_at values in user_activities for the same product...

Comment: @mbd yep, it doesn't fit me... but thank you

Comment: @mbd i think it is impossible task, i will try to change my condition task and will exclude field created_at from resulting table. In this case i can receive needed results. Thank you for your advise